# TOracleDataSet.Filter по двум полям

Tags: delphi-xe

После выполнения запроса в полученном наборе данных необходимо применить фильтрацию по двум полям.

```
with OracleDataSet do 
    begin
    filtred := false;
    filter := 'buh = 1 and fin = 1';
    filtred := true;
    end;

я так понимаю в фильтре нужно писать по правилам языка БД которую использую.
но выдает ошибку синтаксиса.
```

Comment: "но выдает ошибку синтаксиса" - ??

Answer (score 0):

```
//filtred := false;
filtered := false;
...
//filtred := true;
filtered := true;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]